# VS2010 compiler error "is not assignable to parameter type T" not a constraint issue I believe

Tags: c#, .net, generics, rhino-mocks

I don't think its a Rhino mocks related.

Is it a compiler bug ?

The line in 2nd block of code below the ERROR: comment is giving the compiler warning, and I dont understand why. What surprised me even more was that block 3 works.

This one works fine, so i converted it to Generic ActivatePresenterAction2

```cs
private void ActivatePresenterAction1(IListViewHelper<PairDirEntry> lvh)
{
    var args = lvh.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(
            x => x.ActionOnActivateItem(Arg<Action<PairDirEntry>>.Is.Anything));
    Assert.That(args.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(args[0].Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
    var action = (Action<PairDirEntry>)(args[0][0]); // extract the ActivateOnItem action 
    action(_pairDirEntry); // as if ActionOnActivateItem()
}
```

This one works fails to compile on commented line

```cs
private void ActivatePresenterAction2<T>(IListViewHelper<T> lvh) where T : class
{
    var args = lvh.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(
            x => x.ActionOnActivateItem(Arg<Action<T>>.Is.Anything));
    Assert.That(args.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(args[0].Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
    var action = (Action<T>)(args[0][0]); // extract the ActivateOnItem action 
    // 
    // ERROR: is not assignable to parameter type T on hliighted line
    // marking the parameter _pairDirEntry
    // 
    action(_pairDirEntry); // as if ActionOnActivateItem()
}
```

This change to the generic works fine.

```cs
ActivatePresenterAction3(_stubSearchResultListViewHelper)(_pairDirEntry);

private Action<T> ActivatePresenterAction3<T>(IListViewHelper<T> lvh) where T : class
{
    var args = lvh.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(
            x => x.ActionOnActivateItem(Arg<Action<T>>.Is.Anything));
    Assert.That(args.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(args[0].Length, Is.EqualTo(1));
    return (Action<T>)(args[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: Because I have 3 different versions if IListViewHelper<T> with different types of T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler error clearly states, `_pairDirEntry` isn't a `T`, so you can't pass it to a delegate that takes a `T`.

Comment: From what I can see _pairDirEntry is most definitely a T - which is a PairDirEntry in this case or Action1 and Action3 would not work.

Comment: @RobinLuiten: `_pairDirEntry` cannot be a `T`, since `T` is generic parameter of the method and `_pairDirEntry` is a field in the class.

Comment: Thank you, I hive been out most of the day so only just back to this, I undestand where i was lost now. If i had added parameter of T parm and passed that it would be fine.  I am not quite sure why this had be stumped for 2-3 hours before writing up a post to here.

Answer (score 2):

To provide some more detail to SLaks's answer, consider this class:

```
class C<T>
{
    private T t; //assume that this gets assigned somehow
    private void M<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        action(this.t);
    }
}
```

That won't compile because the `T` parameter of the method hides the `T` parameter of the class.  They do not refer to the same type, even though they have the same name.  The type of the action's argument is not the same type as the field `t`.

This can be corrected by removing the type parameter from the method:

```
class C<T>
{
    private T t; //assume that this gets assigned somehow
    private void M(Action<T> action)
    {
        action(this.t);
    }
}
```

Now, the action's argument *is* of the same type as the field `t`.

Comment: The class does not have any other generics, there  is only one generic type in the class and it is the type T on that method.